# How to upload documents using flutter?

Tags: flutter

I built a code to upload images and documents. And when select a image or document show and user can remove.
[image]

but at the   _pickDocument() method show these errors.

[image]

```
class _UploadFilesPageState extends State<UploadFilesPage> {
  List<File> _selectedFiles = [];

  Future<void> _pickImage() async {
    final pickedFile = await ImagePicker().getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    if (pickedFile != null) {
      setState(() {
        _selectedFiles.add(File(pickedFile.path));
      });
    }
  }

  Future<void> _pickDocument() async {
    final result = await FilePickerCross.pick(
      type: FileType.any,
    );
    if (result != null && result.files.isNotEmpty) {
      setState(() {
        _selectedFiles.add(File(result.files.first.path));
      });
    }
  }

  Future<void> _takePhoto() async {
    final pickedFile = await ImagePicker().getImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
    if (pickedFile != null) {
      setState(() {
        _selectedFiles.add(File(pickedFile.path));
      });
    }
  }

  Future<void> _uploadFiles() async {
    // Code to upload files to Firebase Storage
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Upload Files')),
      body: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: _selectedFiles.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                final file = _selectedFiles[index];
                return ListTile(
                  leading: Icon(Icons.attachment),
                  title: Text(file.path),
                  trailing: IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        _selectedFiles.removeAt(index);
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              ElevatedButton.icon(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.file_copy),
                  label: Text('Select Document'),
                  onPressed:_pickDocument,
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: [
              ElevatedButton.icon(
                icon: Icon(Icons.image),
                label: Text('Select Image'),
                onPressed: _pickImage,
              ),

              ElevatedButton.icon(
                icon: Icon(Icons.camera_alt),
                label: Text('Take Photo'),
                onPressed: _takePhoto,
              ),
            ],
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 16),
          ElevatedButton(
            child: Text('Upload'),
            onPressed: _selectedFiles.isEmpty ? null : _uploadFiles,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Used packages
**  file_picker_cross: ^4.0.0**

** image_picker: ^0.8.6+1**

If there is another good package that works, that's okay. For the upload documents